# VBA - Merging a Range from All Workbooks in a Folder and SUBFOLDER

Tags: vba, excel

At the moment my code below works well when I have files only in the main folder called "E:\Dian\Test". (Reads only files copied in the main folder (MyPath) but not the files in the subfolder)

My question is how do I change/add to my existing code to include a loop to include searching through SubFolders, within the E:\Dian\Test folder, for .xlsx files starting with the name "out_*"

Keep in mind my programming skills are not very good.

Thank you :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim myCountFiles As Long
Dim myFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
Dim FirstCell As String
Dim emptyColumn As Long
Dim NextRow As Range

' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.'

'How do you include a loop to include searching through SubFolders, within the E:\Dian\Test folder, for xlsx files starting with the name "out_*"??????????????????????????????????????'

MyPath = "E:\Dian\Test\"

' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
' in the search folder.
Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
   If FilesInPath <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
  Fnum = Fnum + 1
  ReDim Preserve myFiles(1 To Fnum)
  myFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
End If
FilesInPath = Dir()

Loop

' Set various application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Add a new workbook/existing sheet.
If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
Exit Sub
End If

Set BaseWks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1_Input_Data")
With BaseWks
   rnum = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If Fnum > 0 Then
    For Fnum = LBound(myFiles) To UBound(myFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & myFiles(Fnum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets("Summary")

FirstCell = "A4"
Set sourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))
' Test if the row of the last cell is equal to or greater than the row of the first cell.
If RDB_Last(1, .Cells) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
  Set sourceRange = Nothing
End If

End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in column A.
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.UsedRange(rnum, "A"). _
                                Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = Mid(myFiles(Fnum), WorksheetFunction.Find("out_", myFiles(Fnum)) + 4, WorksheetFunction.Find(".xlsx", myFiles(Fnum)) - WorksheetFunction.Find("out_", myFiles(Fnum)) - 4)

                    End With

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)



                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)

                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value


                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If

    Next Fnum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of issue, I have used the Command Shell.  You could use PowerShell, but I've not developed the code for that.

Here is a short routine that will place all the files that have a specific pattern in their name, into an array `vFileList`.  You could then iterate through that array.

Note that the shell `dir` command uses the `\S` and `\B` switches.

> \S means to read the items in this folder and all of the subfolders
>   \B removes all the extraneous information, leaving only the full file path

In your case, you would probably set

```
MyPath = "E:\Dian\Test\out_*.xlsx"



Option Explicit
'set reference to Windows Script Host Object Model
Sub GetFiles()
    Const myPath As String = "D:\Users\Ron\b*.xlsx"
    Dim WSH As WshShell
    Dim vFileList As Variant
Set WSH = New WshShell
vFileList = Split(WSH.Exec("CMD /c dir """ & myPath & """/B /S").StdOut.ReadAll, vbLf)
End Sub
```

Comment: Epic solution! I added it to my library. Can also late-bind without reference: `Dim WSH As Object: Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`. Might want to name `vFileList` to stay consist with OP's naming, `myfiles`.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks. She can name it as she likes.  I like the `v` for Variant.  Only problem with this method is that the `cmd` window opens up while running.  I have also used the `Run` method which allows minimizing the `cmd` window, but then you can't capture the output directly -- you have to pipe it to a file, and then read it.  I would use the latter if I were distributing, (or get into Powershell), but this is good enough for private work.  OH, I like early-binding for `Intellisense`. But use late-binding for distribution.

Comment: Highly appreciate this solution.